# change the first occurrence in a pandas column based on certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

so I would like to change the first number in the number column to +233 given the first number is 0, basically I would like all rows in number to be like that of row Paul
Both columns are string objects.

Expectations:
The first character of the values in the column named `df["numbers"]` should be replaced to `"+233"` if only ==  `"0"`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[ken, 080222333222], 
                   [ben, +233948433], 
                   [Paul, 0800000073]], 
                   columns=['name', 'number'])`
```

Comment: Is the column number in str or int format?

Comment: It’s string format

Comment: please rephrase your question, give an example of a string before and after

Comment: Also, give the expected output. Just to confirm on what I have now

Comment: @balandongiv I have make some changes thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understood your edition, try this:
Notice - I removed the first 0 and replaced it with +233

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["ken", "080222333222"], ["ben", "+233948433"], ["Paul", "0800000073"]], columns=['name', 'number'])


def convert_number(row):
    if row[0] == '0':
        row = "+233" + row[1:]
    return row

df['number'] = df['number'].apply(convert_number)

print(df)
```

Comment: Hi @TomerS, you can use `replace` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can used `replace` directly

```
df['relace_Col']=df.number.str.replace(r'^\d', '+233',1)
```

which produced

```
   name        number       relace_Col
0   ken  080222333222  +23380222333222
1   ben    +233948433       +233948433
2  Paul    0800000073    +233800000073
```

The full code to reproduce the above

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['ken', '080222333222'], ['ben', '+233948433'],
                   ['Paul', '0800000073']], columns=['name', 'number'])



df['relace_Col']=df.number.str.replace(r'^\d', '+233',1)
print(df)
```